# Add class to element if at top of page and user scrolls up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a splash page similar to http://kinkinurbanthai.com/ but I need to re-activate the splash if the user is at the top of the page, and does an additional scroll up to 'request' or activate the splash again.

I have the code working up to the point of reactivating the splash element; but I can't get it to wait for the additional 'scroll up' request.

Here is the code so far that works, minus the locking b/c that isn't doing what I need it to atm. Code: http://jsfiddle.net/teejudp3/2/

```
// Does stuff on load and scrolls
//-------------------------------// 
$(window).on("load scroll",function(e){

    var $window = $(window);

    if ( $window.scrollTop() <= 0 ) {
        $('.splashwrapper').removeClass('remove');
    }


    // hide/show splash screen
    //=========================//
        // chrome/FF
        $('.splashwrapper').bind('DOMMouseScroll', function(e){

            // get scroll direction
            var direction = (function () {

                var delta = (e.type === 'DOMMouseScroll' ?
                    e.originalEvent.detail * -40 :
                    e.originalEvent.wheelDelta);
                    return delta > 0 ? 0 : 1;
            }());

            if( direction === 0 ) {
                // scroll up

            } else {
                // scroll down
                $('.splashwrapper').addClass('remove');                 
            }

            //prevent page fom scrolling
            return false;
        });

        //IE, Opera, Safari
        $('.splashwrapper').bind('mousewheel', function(e){

            // get scroll direction
            var direction = (function () {

                var delta = (e.type === 'DOMMouseScroll' ?
                    e.originalEvent.detail * -40 :
                    e.originalEvent.wheelDelta);
                    return delta > 0 ? 0 : 1;
            }());

            if( direction === 0 ) {
                // scroll up

            } else {
                // scroll down
                $('.splashwrapper').addClass('remove');                 
            }

            //prevent page fom scrolling
            return false;
        });

        // touch device - uses touchSwipe.js
        $(".splashwrapper").swipe({
            swipeUp:function() {
                $('.splashwrapper').addClass('remove');
            }
        });

});
```

I've tried to stop the users scroll if they go to <= 1 scroll top position but this doesn't seem to give the wanted affect.

```
// temporarily lock users scroll position
var $window = $(window), previousScrollTop = 1, scrollLock = false;
$window.scroll(function(event) {     
    if(scrollLock) {
        $window.scrollTop(previousScrollTop); 
    }
    previousScrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
});

// if at 1px from top, stop scroll from going up one time
if ( $window.scrollTop() <= 1 ) {
    scrollLock = true;
    $window.scrollTop( 1, 0);
    setTimeout(function() {
        scrollLock = false;
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this working by re-working the stop-point section - aka I was overthinking it.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/teejudp3/6/

```
    var $window = $(window);

    if ( $window.scrollTop() === 0 && $('.splashwrapper').hasClass('ready') ) {
        $window.scrollTop(1);
        $('.splashwrapper').removeClass('ready').removeClass('remove');
    }   

    if ( $window.scrollTop() === 0 && !$('.splashwrapper').hasClass('ready') ) {
        $window.scrollTop(1);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.splashwrapper').addClass('ready');
        }, 500);
    }
```